# Ubuntu|TortoiseHg: How to install tortoisehg of concretical version? (I need tortoisehg with 3.3.2 Mercurial version)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mercurial, tortoisehg, linux-mint

How to install tortoisehg of concretical version? (I need tortoisehg with 3.3.2 Mercurial version).

I'm confused. Recently I installed Tortoise from `add-apt-repository ppa:tortoisehg-ppa/releases` repository. And it installed for me programm with 3.3.1 Mercurial version. It called conflict.

Or tell me please, how I can install latest version of `Hg` and `TortoiseHg`?
Thanks you!

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related site askubuntu.com. Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Good luck.

Comment: try it: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=102322